# Error while running scrapy web crawler

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            title = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

However, when I try to call up the spider, I get the following error message:

```
[example] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1178, in mainLoop
        self.runUntilCurrent()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/base.py", line 800, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 368, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 464, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/Users/andy2/Documents/Python/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/example.py", line 18, in parse
        print title, link, desc
    exceptions.NameError: global name 'link' is not defined
```

Is there anything I can do to make this code work?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate a [`Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector) and pass `response` as an argument. Also, your imports are not correct. Here's the fixed version of the spider:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import Spider


class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        for li in sel.xpath('//ul/li'):
            title = li.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            link = li.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            desc = li.xpath('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```